# Unicode Characters to image

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

With a REST-request I receive an image in following format (I shortened the string):

```
{
  "logo": "\ufffdPNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0001\ufffd\u0000\u0000\u0000\ufffd\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000*F5\ufffd\u0000\u0000\u0000\tpHYs\u0000\u0000\u000e\ufffd\u0000\u0000\u000e\ufffd\u0001\ufffd+\u000e\u001b\u0000\u0000 \u0000IDATx\u0001\ufffd\u0007\ufffdd\ufffdQ'\u001c\ufffde\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd;fwg\ufffdӮ\ufffd\ufffd.2.."
}
```

How can I convert this into an image? I have tried various things, but nothing seems to work. Is it even valid?

Comment: looks like the beginning of a PNG file, yes.

Comment: @flowtron No, PNG files don't start with a \uFFFD char.

Comment: @user5417542 The data is not valid. By the looks of it, all bytes larger than \x7F have been replaced by \uFFFD. I'm afraid this is not reversible, so you'll have to see if you can get the source in another way.